# Cancel ApplePay and GooglePay dialog

Tags: android, ios, react-native, detox

I'm trying to test an App using Detox and I want to programmatically click on the cancel button or any other button on the (Apple|Google)Pay dialog and I can't find a way to do that !

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not supported, because the alert is displayed from a different process. The suggested way to tackle this is to mock this API and not display it when testing.